# Some patterns causing TypeError in model-json-js

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am trying to use a Json schema to validate a JSON model

I have installed node module model-json-js

One property is using a pattern to try and match the expression.  Using 0-9 does not cause any errors.

> ```
> properties: {
>     test: {
>         type: "string",
>         pattern: "^[0-9]*$"
>     },
> ```

but using the same pattern, but [a-z] does cause an error

> ```
> properties: {
>     test: {
>         type: "string",
>         pattern: "^[a-z]*$"
>     },
> ```

```
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'validate')
    at validate (/Users/dave/Documents/Projects/playground/json-model/node_modules/model-json-js/dist/Model.js:1:1942)
```

I've tried escaping, but cannot find a format that works using letters.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the problem was not in the regex expression, it was in the starting value of the model, not matching the regex expression.  The error doesn't get caught in my try/catch, it crashes in the module when the model is being built but at least I don't have to relearn regex to get this working...